# set multiple variables to false with one method Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, methods

I have the following variables:

```
var1 = null;
var2 = null;
var3 = null;
var4 = null;
var5 = null;
```

and the following buttons:

```
<button>btn1</button>
<button>btn2</button>
<button>btn3</button>
<button>btn4</button>
<button>btn5</button>
<button>btnNull</button>
```

what i want to do is to set the var1 to true and all the others to false by clicking on btn1, the same behavior with the other 4 buttons and set all variables to null by clicking on btnNull.

what i did is the following:

```
btn1(){
  this.var1=true;
  this.var2=this.var3=this.var4=this.var5=false;
}

btn2(){
  this.var2=true;
  this.var1=this.var3=this.var4=this.var5=false;
}

btn3(){
  this.var3=true;
  this.var1=this.var2=this.var4=this.var5=false;
}

btn4(){
  this.var4=true;
  this.var1=this.var2=this.var3=this.var5=false;
}

btn5(){
  this.var5=true;
  this.var1=this.var2=this.var3=this.var4=false;
}

btnNull(){
  this.var1=this.var2=this.var3=this.var4=this.var5=null;
}
```

and used that five methods each one in different buttons like this:

```
<button (click)="btn1()">btn1</button>
<button (click)="btn2()">btn2</button>
<button (click)="btn3()">btn3</button>
<button (click)="btn4()">btn4</button>
<button (click)="btn5()">btn5</button>
<button (click)="btnNull()">btnNull</button>
```

that's a lot of code and doesn't really look very good, how can i achieve the same behavior with one or two single methods?

Comment: I guess this is a simplified use case? If so, is the types of the variables always going to be the same? Is the number of variables fixed or dynamic?

Comment: it's not really a simplified use case, in the project the name of the variables is different, but the structure is exactly the same (i'm working on the website for an orchestra and i want to show the instrument families by clicking on a button, then the divs with the members of that family will check the variable of that family and will be shown or not with *ngIf) the types will always be the same and the number of variables is fixed.

Comment: Why don't you use an array instead? It'd be cleaner that way I think. And more scalable if one day you decide to have 10 variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array.. but I wouldn't use `var` as a variable name since it's reserved.

component.ts

```
vals = [null, null, null, null, null];
```

then in component.html

```
<button *ngFor="let val of vals; let i =index"
        (click)="vals.fill(false); vals[i] = true">btn {{i + 1}}</button>

<button (click)="vals.fill(null);">btnNull</button>

<p *ngFor="let val of vals; let i = index">val{{i}} = {{val}}</p>
```